# Using the CSS-class active with PHP

Tags: php, frameworks

I'm using Semantic UI with PHP to create a website and I got a minor problem. And I think this problem can be answered regardless if you've used Semantic UI or not, since I would expect that it's common to all frameworks.

I have a header.php where I store all HTML containing `<head>` and the `<nav>`, and then I am using the 'include header.php' on all sites. So my problem is that I can't use the CSS-class 'active' (marks what site the user is currently on) on the current website I am on since the `<nav>` will be the same on all websites.

Anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: `header.php` contains PHP. Add logic so it isn't absolutely identical everywhere.

Comment: But I want it to be identical, except for the CSS active class.

Comment: Then that's the bit you need to write code to make different!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option you have is to add a function that echos the headers.  The function could take a parameter that allows you to say which page you were on and use if statements to know which nav link to apply the class "active" to.

The function would look something like this:

```
function header_html($page){
    result = "";
    //add other header info to result
    $result.="\n<a href=\"page1.php\" ";
    $result.= $page == "page1.php" ? "class=\"active\"" : "";
    $result.=">Page 1</a>";

    $result.="\n<a href=\"page2.php\" ";
    $result.=$page == "page2.php" ? "class=\"active\"" : "";
    $result.=">Page 2</a>";
    //repeat as needed

    //add other closing header tags
    echo $result;
}
```

Your PHP would look like this:

```
<?php
include header.php;
header_html("page1.php");
?>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!